# Data Studio: regex in not working when character appears more than once

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I need to capture everything between "-" characters.

For example:

**Example 1:**     `vivo - La reina soy yo` I need: `La reina soy yo`.

**Example 2:**     `VOD - Te volveré a encontrar - Temporada 1 - Cap 23` I need: `Te volveré a encontrar`.

I've this regex, that is only working for example 1 cases:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Etiqueta de evento, ".*\\- (.*) ?\\-?")
```

Google documentation for REGEXP_EXTRACT [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487?hl=en)

What I need to change, so it works for string like example 2?

**It should return what is highlighted in green, not in yellow.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Etiqueta de evento, "^.*? - (.*?)(?: - |$)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5lLhK8/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `-`  - a  `-`  string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?: - |$)` - a non-capturing group matching either  `-`  or end of string.